# Protecting vs Defending a system

Tags: defense, protection, terminology

What is the difference between saying `defending` a system from attacks or `protecting` a system from attacks?

This question might be trivial to most of you but I really don't see the fine line here. In fact, I don't see a difference (maybe because English is my second language) but I was told that there is a difference!

Comment: I don't think there is a difference personally. If you are defending, you are protecting. Indeed, a quick look in the dictionary confirms that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of a computer system being attacked, both Protecting and Defending are considered the same.

If this were a physical attack, then there would be a difference, but in IT Security both Protection and Defense are the same.

There is a term called Protected Storage, but this is not the same context

Defense could mean retaliation, where Protection would not. However, retaliation is not a desirable solution in IT Security, and is not directly effective.

In my opinion, Defense is a less desirable term, because computer systems deal in absolutes; Protected could seem more absolute, where Defended implies a finite amount of resources.

Personally, I would not use either term. Instead I would say 'Securing a system' from attacks. This is because success or failure when attacking a vulnerability is an absolute. This is quite different from physical attacks in which relate to 'strength' on both sides. DoS is an exception to this distinction.